# Apache with tomcat and webapps

Tags: tomcat, rewrite, url, domain-name, apache2

I am completely new to configuring tomcat. I'm trying to setup apache in front and just have tomcat act as a servlet. So far everything is working fairly well and I got it all setup, but the only thing I can't figure out is the war files work now.

Before it would deploy the war file say I had

```
 tomcat/webapps/ROOT
 tomcat/webapps/manager
 tomcat/webapps/app1
 tomcat/webapps/app1.war
```

I throw the app1.war in there and have it extract. Then I go to mywebsite.com/app1 and it comes up at that url.

How do I get that to work again to where I can deploy the war file and go the app?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question well.
You could go to *mywebsite.com/manager* end click there on undeploy at your app. To access tomcat manager you have to edit *tomcat/conf/tomcat-user.xml* to something like that and restart tomcat:

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="tomcat,manager-gui"/>
```

You also could stop tomcat and then remove *tomcat/webapps/app1* and *tomcat/webapps/app1.war* and copy the *app1.war* there again.

But not sure, if it's that what you meant.